# SharedPreferences getting only one string

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to get if question answered or not, but it gets the status of the last question for all the questions ( if answered or not )

Can someone help me to make it get the status of every question?

Here is the codes of my application:

```
public class Question{
    boolean answered;
    public static int id;
    String userAnswer;
    String QuestionP = LogoQuiz.QuestionP;

    public Question(int i, Context context){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(QuestionP, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = i;
        answered = pref.getBoolean("answered"+i, false);
    }


}
```

and for calculating how many questions:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public static ArrayList<Question> ques;
    public static final String QuestionP = "QuestionSettings";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(QuestionP, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        -------- activity ----------
        -------- activity ----------

            ques = new ArrayList<Question>();
            for(int i = 0; i < QuestionsA.mPucIds.length; i++)
            {
                ques.add(new Question(i, Main.this));
                CharSequence text = "";
                if(pref.getBoolean("FirstRun", true))
                {   
                text = "First Run";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", false);
                editor.putBoolean("answered"+i, false);
                editor.commit();

                }
            }
        }
}
```

And for answer

```
int id = Question.id;
editor.putBoolean("answered"+id, true).commit();
```

Comment: My suggestion is to log the key from preference so you can check if you are saving them in the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `static` modifier for a variable, no matter how many instances of that class you create the value of that variable will remain the same in all of the instances.

So try removing the `static` modifier for the `id` and then use a constructor call like:

```
int id = new Question(i, Main.this).id;
```

so that a new instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've declared your **id** variable as **static** that's why it gets the last value , remove that modifier and you're done.

**EDITED** Well i assume when the question gets answered you get the **id instance field** from **ques** **Question instance** and by that id you cal

```
editor.putBoolean("answered"+id, true).commit();
```

Comment: but when I remove it I get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Question.id"

Comment: Because you can't reference id instance variable using Question class you want the instance of it say 'question' (question.id). I Edited my answer maybe it'll help.

Comment: And is there a way to get it if I removed "static"?

Comment: yes you must remove static modifier if you don't want to get the last value

Comment: When I remove it I get Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Question.id

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put the

```
editor.commit()
```

outside the for loop. It does not need to commit so many times. Also, check the 'i' value by putting a

```
Log.d("i value", Integer.toString(i));
```

in your Question class to make sure you are receiving the correct value to be checked. The code seems fine.

EDIT:

Change

```
int id = Question.id;
```

to

```
int id = new Question(i, Main.this).id
```

The static variable 'id' is the same for all the copies of objects of Question.

I would suggest reading up on static variables and methods in Java.

Comment: Still the same problem.